Evaluate $\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x^2}dx$
Evaluate $\int\limits_0^\infty x^ne^{-x^2}dx$. Hint: use that $\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.
My approach:
base case:
If $n=0$, then $\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$
If $n=1$, then we perform integration by parts and get $\int\limits_0^\infty x^1e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}$.
induction hypothesis:
1.) if $n$ is even, then $\int\limits_0^\infty x^ne^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{\frac{n+2}{2}}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}(2k-1)$
2.) if $n$ is odd, then $\int\limits_0^\infty x^ne^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}2k$.
(I got these formulas from tinkering around by pluggin in some specific numbers for $n$)
induction step $n\to n+1$:
if $n+1$ is even, then
\begin{align*}
\int\limits_0^\infty x^{n+1}e^{-x^2}dx=\underset{=0}{\underbrace{x^{n}e^{-x^2}dx\Big|_0^\infty}}+\frac{n}{2}\underset{\text{we apply induction hypothesis 1.)}}{\underbrace{\int\limits_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x^2}dx}}=\frac{n}{2}\left( \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(2k-1)\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{\frac{n+3}{2}}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{n+1}{2}}(2k-1)
\end{align*}
if $n+1$ is odd, then
\begin{align*}
\int\limits_0^\infty x^{n+1}e^{-x^2}dx=\underset{=0}{\underbrace{x^{n}e^{-x^2}dx\Big|_0^\infty}}+\frac{n}{2}\underset{\text{we apply induction hypothesis 2.)}}{\underbrace{\int\limits_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x^2}dx}}=\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}2k\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{\frac{n+2}{2}}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}2k.
\end{align*}
Finally, we see that the integral delivers some kind of product of even or odd numbers $<n$. I am not sure if this is correct because it seems a bit complicated. Maybe someone knows a more elegant solution or can give me feedback?

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1537455/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110913/42969

There are 2 questions instead of 1 in your post: 1) is my proof correct, and 2) are there simpler solutions. If the main one is the first, this prevents us to close it as a duplicate. But then it is lacking focus: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

You can directly have
$$\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x^2}\, dx
= \int_0^\infty x^{n/2} e^{-x}{dx\over2\sqrt{x}} = \Gamma\left({n + 1\over 2}\right)$$
using the substitution $x \rightarrow \sqrt{x}$.
